# Relationship between overwall SQALE Rating calculation and the technical debts?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Sorry if this is a simple question...

We noticed that we are getting SQALE rating = A for most of our projects, which
raise concerns from the dev team.

For some projects, we noticed that most modules are given technical debts = B, or C but not > B, but the SQALE rating would be = A.

We are wondering if this makes sense because shouldn't the average at most B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQALE rating is a ratio of the remediation cost to the estimated cost to develop your current code base. In a large code base a few B modules could easily be dwarfed by the size of the code base as a whole.

If you're after low-level detail, [you can find it](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SQALE+Plugin#SQALEPlugin-UnderstandingSQALERatings) in the documentation of the retired SQALE plugin.